# Difference between PowerShell Console and PowerShell ISE

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

What are differences between PowerShell Console and PowerShell ISE. I am asking this question in context of Profiles in PowerShell. Because PowerShell Console and PowerShell ISE both have differnet profiles.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From [Differences between the ISE and PowerShell console](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2009/04/17/differences-between-the-ise-and-powershell-console.aspx):-

> 1. Limited support for interactive console apps, try cmd.exe, then try
>      cmd.exe /k
>
>    a) cmd.exe /c dir still works though, and more information is available here
>      http://blogs.msdn.com/powershell/archive/2009/02/04/console-application-non-support-in-the-ise.aspx
> 2. Console Application output is not colorful
> 3. STA by default
>
>    a) Try $host.Runspace.ApartmentState
>
>    b) powershell is MTA by default (ApartmentState shows up as Unknown) but can be started in sta mode with powershell -sta.
>
>    c) ISE is always STA
> 4. No support for the [Console] class, try [console]::BackgroundColor 
>      = 'white'.
>
>    a) In general, scripts should use the host API's (write-host, instead of the [Console] class, so that they work in both the console,
>      ISE, Remoting and other shells.
> 5. Limited (close to zero) support on $host.UI.RawUI. We only support
>      the colors and title
>
>    a) The colors are better set in $psISE.Options, because you can set those to any color, not just console colors
> 6. Custom/dead-simple more. See gc function:more
>
>    a) The ISE has no pager
> 7. Start-Transcript does not work in the ISE
> 8. Some Thread Culture differences
>
>    a) If you’re in a non-console supported culture (eg Arabic) ISE will have Get-Culture as ar-sa, and powershell.exe will have
>      Get-Culture as en-us (or some other fallback)
> 9. Suggestions dont work in the ISE
>
>    a) For example, in C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer" if you execute iexplore.exe
>
>    b) You'll only see this in PowerShell.exe Suggestion [3,General]: The command iexplore.exe was not found, but does exist in the current
>      location. Windows PowerShe ll doesn't load commands from the current
>      location by default. If you trust this command, instead type
>      ".\iexplore.exe".
>
>    See "get-help about_Command_Precedence" for more details.
> 10. The ISE runs a different profile
>
>     a) The ISE profile is in Microsoft.PowerShellISE_profile.ps1, and powershell is in Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1
>
>     b) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613488(VS.85).aspx
>
>     c)
>       http://www.leeholmes.com/blog/TheStoryBehindTheNamingAndLocationOfPowerShellProfiles.aspx
>
>     d) You can use the common profile, stored in $profile.CurrentUserAllHosts to make it run in both shells
> 11. Only the ISE has $psISE
>
>     a)it gets access to http://psisecream.codeplex.com/, and http://blogs.msdn.com/powershell/archive/2008/12/29/powershell-ise-can-do-a-lot-more-than-you-think.aspx

Comment: Actually PowerShell console has reverted back to STA for its default for both V3 and V4.  The only version of PowerShell Console that used MTA was V2.  FWIW *each* host, including ISE and NuGet within Visual Studio, gets to have its own profile script to give users a chance to do host specific initialization and configuration.  The profile.ps1 file is global to all hosts. Try executing `$profile | fl -Force`.