# Powershell ISE returning empty string but working fine in shell

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

I have the following command:

```
$startDate='01/02/2013'
$endDate='26/03/2014'
Search-AdminAuditLog -Cmdlets set-mailboxsearch -StartDate $startDate -EndDate $endDate | where {$_.cmdletparameters.name -notcontains "inplaceholdenabled"}|Add-Member -Name "SearchName" -MemberType ScriptProperty -PassThru -Value {Get-MailboxSearch -Identity $this.objectmodified} | select "objectmodified","Caller","Rundate","cmdletname",@{Name="SearchName";Expression={$_.searchname.Name}}
```

It returns:

```
ObjectModified : XXXXXXXX
Caller         : Administrator
RunDate        : 25/03/2014 4:33:17 PM
CmdletName     : Set-MailboxSearch
SearchName     : 

ObjectModified : AAMkADQyZDMxY2UwL 
Caller         : Administrator
RunDate        : 25/03/2014 9:35:02 AM
CmdletName     : Set-MailboxSearch
SearchName     :
```

The SearchName field is always an empty string when I run in PowerShell ISE, but if I copy and run the same command in shell, it returns SearchName as "test search 2 to 7" which is the required value.

Why is the behaviour different in both places? What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is maybe in this duplicate thread, basically ISE is not the same as the console and has many caveats for you to learn.

[Difference between PowerShell Console and PowerShell ISE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20022976/difference-between-powershell-console-and-powershell-ise)

In other words, probably nothing wrong with your script, ISE is known to have `issues`.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2009/04/17/differences-between-the-ise-and-powershell-console.aspx